# get Id of input field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have input in grid, which each unique ID, output as following;

```
<a href="#" class="SearchUser_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_getUserListByGroupID()" id="2"></a>
```

I want to know what is equivalent to $(this).attr("ID") in javaScript

```
 function load_getUserListByGroupID()
{

    var selectedGroupID = document.getElementById('input');

    alert(selectedGroupID);


}
```

Comment: `this.getAttribute('id')` or `this.id`

Comment: Read a basic tutorial on the DOM API. You'll find useful routines there such as `getAttribute`. StackOverflow tends to function as a poor substitute for just reading the documentation.

Comment: The real answer here is `addEventListener`, that way you'd solve the issue with the inline handler **and** get access to `this`

Comment: Specifically, you could consult https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id. This was the first result that popped up when I googled "html element id".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply get it using `.id` attribute like this:

```
this.id;
```

Or you can also use `.getAttribute()` method:

```
this.getAttribute('id')
```

So your example should be, like this:

```js
 function load_getUserListByGroupID(element) {
   alert(element.id);
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="SearchUser_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_getUserListByGroupID(this)" id="2">aa</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` to onclick event handler. Then you can directly get its id.

Use

```
<a href="#" class="SearchUser_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_getUserListByGroupID(this)" id="2"></a>
```

*Script*

```
 function load_getUserListByGroupID(elem){
    alert(elem.id);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable,

```
onClick="reply_click(this.id)"

function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
```

Add the OnClick function the element you'd like, this will also throw the ID value when processing to the function.

Hope this helps :)